NodeJS Multer upload request does upload image to the intended path but request status is pending and blocks the next request
I'm doing multiple fetch requests in function saveProduct, one request to upload the file to /public/images directory, the other one is to upload data related to the product to the product table, the first request POST /api/upload works fine and it does indeed upload the file to the intended directory, but then after that the function stops working, it doesn't do request POST /api/new-product, neither it executes any of the rest of the code, the toast doesn't show ..etc, in the network tab i noticed that the request status is pending, and it's just keeps pending forever, the code was working with no problem before doing this multiple fetch requests.
Front side
  const saveProduct = async () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", product.image);
    setSubmitted(true);
    if (!product.image || !product.name|| !product.price) {
      return;
    }

    let _products = [...products];
    let _product = { ...product };

      Promise.all([
        await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/upload", {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        }),
        await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/new-product", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(product),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }),
      ]).then(() => {
        _products.push(_product);
        toast.current.show({
          severity: "success",
          summary: "Successful",
          detail: "Product Created",
          life: 5000,
        });
        setProducts(_products);
        setProductDialog(false);
        setProduct(emptyProduct);
      });


  };

server side
import multer from "multer";
// Initialize router
const routes = Router({ strict: true });

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    return cb(null, "./public/images");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    return cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

routes.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);
});

routes.post(
  "/new-team-member",
  [
    // Validation for user name
    body("name")
      .trim()
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage("product name must not be empty")
      .isLength({ min: 10 })
      .withMessage("Full name must be at least 10 characters in length")
      .escape(),

    // Validation for password length
    body("price")
      .trim()
      .not
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage("price must not be empty"),
  ],
  // tokenValidation(),
  // validate, // Middleware to handle validation errors
  (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { name, price, image } = req.body;

      DB.execute(
        "INSERT INTO `team` (`name`,`price`,`image`) VALUES (?,?,?)",
        [name, price, image]
      );
      res.status(201).json({
        name: name,
        price: price,
        image: image,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);


It happens because you're not sending any response back to the frontend from your server in upload api try sending response with res.status.().json({})

i believe it happens because im awaiting for every fetch on its own, it rather should be await Promise.all([...])

it happens because im using await for every fetch, it should rather be await Promise.all([...])
      await Promise.all([
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/upload", {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        }),
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/new-team-member", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(product),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }),
      ]).then(() => {
            ...
      });

